# jQuery Keypress Event

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm dealing with two text box - using jQuery I want that every time the user updates the value in the first box , the same value will apear in the second box.

```
​<input type="text" class="pack"/ >
​<input type="text" class="pack2"/>​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​

​$(".pack").keypress(function(){
    $(".pack2").val($(this).val());
});​​​​​
```

The problem is that if I type a letter in "pack" , it won't appear in "pack2" right away - I'll have to type another letter, and then the first letter will appear in pack2

You can check the fiddle - 
http://jsfiddle.net/itamarperetz/jGXyA/

What can I so pack2 will be updated right away?

Any suggestion will be helpful,
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Try changing the `keypress` event to `keyup`.

```
​$(".pack").keyup(function() {
    $(".pack2").val($(this).val());
});​​​​​
```

### [jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jGXyA/1/)

Answer (score 1):

That's because `keypress` is fired before the character is actually added to the input-field. Try using `keyup` instead, which is fired after the character is added to the input-field.

Answer (score 1):

**Check out this [working answer](http://jsfiddle.net/jGXyA/2/).**

You should use `keyup` rather than `keypress`.

Check out the API [here](http://api.jquery.com/keyup/).

Answer (score 1):

Use keyup event

```
$(".pack").keyup(function(){
    $(".pack2").val($(".pack").val());
});​
```